# Allow remote access MySQL, Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, netbeans

Im trying to allow remote accecss to MySQL on my Ubuntu server (VPS).

Im trying to access the database through an Java application Im building in Netbeans. Netbeans kick the following error message, when trying to connect:

> Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/xxxxxx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
>   using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (null, message from server: "Host
>   'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")

I have followed this guide when trying to connect to my MySQL server through Netbeans: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fk2EkBs-Oq4

**MySQL**

MySQL running on standard port 3306.
In /etc/mysql/my.cnf I have comment out the following row:

> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

So no bind-address exist in my my.cnf -file.

**UFW**

I have UFW installed on my server. ufw status numbered looks like this:

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    MY-IP-ADDRESS*
[ 4] 3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    MY-IP-ADDRESS*
[ 6] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] 3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

*MY-IP-ADDRESS = The ip address I have "out" to the internet, which I recive from: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

What am I doing wrong and why cant I connect?

**EDIT**:
The thing is that if i bind in my.cnf I can only bind one IP. I need localhost access for my live websites running on the vps and also access from my dev-computer (which this thread is aiming). My thoughts was to remove bind in my.cnf to allow all and then grant access through my firewall UFW to localhost and my dev-computer.

Comment: your bind is incorrect. you're binding to the localhost address, meaning mysql won't listen for connections from the outside world.

Comment: Refer here : http://www.preprogrammer.com/allow-remote-connections-to-mysql-server-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use **Connect via `PuTTY` and tunnel**
look at the bottom of this answer

---

I assume you have a mysql administration tool.
The following will look depending on the tool used linux or something else, but work the same.

Login there and go into the user administration.

[image]

If you have installation a normal Mysql, then there should be only root without a host.

From the moment when you have created a localhost, then Mysql assume that you want to manage multiple hosts.

[image]

Create a existing host. A computer name exists in your network. Here `root@dxxxxx-p`. This should be created under the `root` user.

That's not all now you still have all your tables grant permissions.
Here `pricelist` has no assigned permissions

[image]

But sample has all permissions

[image]

With multiple host administration is for example.

A computer with two accessible names

- myComp1 : IP 192.168.0.101
- localhost : IP 127.0.0.1

If you now connect on the same computer with "mysql -h localhost -u root ...." you get the permissions you have assigned to localhost.

You might think because `localhost` and `myComp1` is the same computer.
Now automatically `myComp1` has the same permission as `localhost` .
But this is not so. So be careful.

### Connect via `PuTTY` and tunnel

when you connect you with PuTTY, everything described above is not necessary.

With tunnel you connect as root@localhost on the ubuntu server.

Localhost is here somewhat misleading because it does not relate to your windows computer but on the localhost on the ubuntu server.

Access Your MySQL Server Remotely Over SSH

**So you’ve got MySQL on your web server, but it’s only opened to local ports by default for security reasons.**

If you want to access your database from a client tool like the `MySQL Query Browser` or **Netbeans** , normally you’d have to open up access from your local IP address… but that’s not nearly as secure.

So instead, we’ll just use port-forwarding through an SSH tunnel, so your MySQL client thinks it’s connecting to your localhost machine, but it’s really connecting to the other server through the tunnel.

[image]

Go to SSH->Tunnels

[image]

After clicked `Save`

Make sure that the MySQL server are off on the Windows computer.
I'm using `MySQL System Tray Monitor`.

With a right click, I see all the options.

[image]

click `Open`

[image]

If you have done all the settings for `SSH` on ubuntu right, that should appear here.   (If NOT Search for Ubuntu SSH and Putty on the web)

[image]

Do not forget: Now that you've logged on ubuntu server you have all the right as root@localhost on the server itself, since root@localhost has all rights, you need not create a host and create permissions to schemas

[image]

Now on your windows computer open `MySql Query Browser`

[image]

Now connect to localhost (remember this localhost means localhost on ubuntu)
**You can use in Netbeans the same settings to connect to Mysql on Ubuntu**

[image]

Mysql Query Browser opens you can work on your Databases on UBUNTU

[image]

### Netbeans

[image]

After closing `New Connection Wizard`
A new connection is created with all Databases On Mysql Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Hat off for this super guide and explanation! Also thanks for your patient! Now it works as a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

To

```
bind-address = YOUR-IP-ADDRESS*
```

Comment: The thing is that if i bind in my.cnf I can only bind one IP. I need localhost access for my live websites running on the vps and also access from my dev-computer (which this thread is aiming). My thoughts was to remove bind in my.cnf to allow all and then grant access through my firewall UFW to localhost and my dev-computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access to that database :

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

And also updated the firewall rules something like :

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```