# Delphi XE7 embedded MySQL database

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

I used BDE before and deployed it with my apps and databases, and everything was very easy to setup. Now, I have Delphi XE7, FireDAC components and a MySQL database. Since I have WAMP, MySQL works for me and my database is located withing my local server. I would like to use my app on another computer, which has no servers running. Is it possible to do? I tried it today and all got is a few more gray hairs. I tried to do things listed here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)

I have my .exe file. I have 'libmysqld.dll' in the same folder. I have 'data' folder which has another folder ('ccvs'), and in it I have .frm and .idb files (MySQL database with InnoDB storage engine).
I even tried with a 'my.ini' file. In the end, I installed MySQL server and administrator (I think it was the name of the application). I copied my database to 'c:\programdata\mysql...\data' and I could finally browse it, but I could not access the database. Even though I could visually see it, program told me it does not exist.

I tried this as well: `www.da-soft.com/forums/anydac-general-english/howto-configure-and-setup-a-mysql-embedded-server.html`
Downloaded the sample app, but those components do not exist anymore and I cannot load the project successfully.

Also this looked great, but my components don't have those options... https://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/loggingembeddedserver.htm

I would like to avoid installing MySQL and embed the database if possible.

Comment: If you're going to connect to a server that is running *outside*, you're not supposed to use MySQL Embedded server library, but a client library that will connect you there (so I guess, because there's not much more we can do for now, is that *I have 'libmysqld.dll' in the same folder...* should rather be *I have 'libmysql.dll' in the same folder*).

Comment: you can have a look [here mysql remote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27553279/1322642) . Hope it helps.

Comment: If I understand you corectly you want to use local database. Right? If that is true then I suggest you try looking at using of SQLite http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Local_SQL_(FireDAC)

Comment: @TLama, sorry if the text was a bit long. No, no outside server. I want to run my app on a machine with no MySQL installed on it. I want all my files (app and database) in one place - my app folder and its subfolders. No programdata or program files or user folder... Just like this guy made it http://www.da-soft.com/forums/anydac-general-english/howto-configure-and-setup-a-mysql-embedded-server.html

Comment: @SilverWarrior I will have to take a better look at that.