# Delphi - ZEOS MySQL - access denied

Tags: mysql, delphi, zeos

I am trying to connect to my mysql database server (version 5.6) on the web, from Delphi 7 application...

With Mysql Workbench, it works OK, i can run select queries with my test user (the same user that not working in Delphi 7)...

In Delphi, where using TZEosConn 7.1.4-stable  , typed correct hostname for DB server, correct username and password...  (parameter loginprompt = false)
When I change "connected" to true, everything working OK...

But when i am trying to execute a simple query:

zq.SQL.Text:='SELECT field FROM database.TABLE where id='+inttostr(x)+';';
zq.ExecSQL;

where **zq** is TZQuery, and **x** is integer,

I got this error:  **EZSQLException ..  SELECT Command denied for @my_internet_hostname **

When i am logged in MySQL Workbench, i see the same user with wildcard session, like mydbuser@% , the same select works fine

So i think, the problem is in ZEOS component, it adding automatically my internet provider hostname...

On the mysql server i have wildcard hostnames allowed  ( simply - '%'  - so all hosts can access my MYSql DB )

Can someone suggest me, what is the problem with my ZEOS component???

PS: Sorry for my english and formatting

Comment: you can have a look at my answer here. Don't read too far only the part "permisson for a table" . The other part is not related to that.[permission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27553279/1322642). Maybe it helps.

Comment: @moskito-x thanks for an answer, i think there is no problem with table permissions, because from my local PC (same hosname IP address, but different application)  - the same thing working on mysql workbench, and unfortunately, the same thing not working in Delphi with Zeos components...  Problem is, as i said, zeos component is adding "wrong" hostname after username - i.e. user@11-22-33-44.provider.com    and the correct username must be user@%

Comment: there is no user@% . You always get the host where the connection comes from.

Comment: This is the picture from MySQL WorkBench, where everything works fine:  http://i67.tinypic.com/11l0bkh.png

Comment: Remeber : your connection is OK . Only the user has no permission to the **SELECT** Command

Comment: User has granted everything, except GRANT permission...  And on a mysql server side, wildcard hosts are allowed

Comment: look at the database on server look for the table you want access. and show me a screenshot of the permission.

Comment: I have empty table Information_schema.TABLE_PRIVILEGES  - can it be a problem?

Comment: just for a moment add a user  user@11-22-33-44.provider.com to the server. Give him for that table select, update, alter table permission. and try again.

Comment: I added a hostname to allowed hosts on the server, not helped...  then I recreated the test user, flushed privileges, and everything working fine now..  weird...   But thanks for idea, now , my problem is solved...

Answer (score 0):

Does your MySQL server is from internet ?

- first of all : does your internet provider allows you to direct access to MySQL Database with a pipe/socket connexion ? Usually internet provider don't allow this because of security matters. (They can open a special IP/Port for this if you ask them).
- Second : did you have the grant option ? this can cause problem with ZEOS component.

  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'

  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

If i remember well, After i change privilege like this works. it was with Local network mysql Server (with EasyPHP and WAMP tested).

I would also advise you to connect with a **DSN string** : check below the way to connect :

http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1547

```
var
  dsn : string;
begin
  dsn := 'zdbc:mysql://192.168.2.60:3306/world?username=root;password=dev';
```

U can use it for your ZEOSConnexion initialize, and also be careful what is the Charset used : **iso-8859-1, iso-8859-15, utf-8, ansi**. Because **Delphi 7 using ANSI**, and internet servers use often others like UTF-8.

anyway i see an error in your code :

```
zq.SQL.Text:='SELECT field FROM database.TABLE where id='+inttostr(x)+';';
zq.ExecSQL;
```

ExecSQL is used to UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE commands, usually for a select command that return records it's more convenient to use open command :

```
zq.Close;
zq.SQL.Text:='SELECT field FROM database.TABLE where id='+inttostr(x)+';';
zq.Open;
```

I give many path to investigate, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you must add some line in a properties of your TZConnection component:

before opening connection with your TZConnection component try this:

```
function openConnection(BD, User, Host, Pass: string; DBConnection: TZConnection): boolean;
begin
    Result:= false;
    if DBConnection = nil then exit;

    DBConnection.HostName := Host; // Host name to connect
    DBConnection.Protocol := 'mysql-5';
    DBConnection.Port     := 3306; //default port
    DBConnection.Database := DB; // your database name
    DBConnection.User     := User;
    DBConnection.Password := Pass;
    DBConnection.Properties.clear;
    DBConnection.Properties.Add('CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS=1');
    DBConnection.Properties.Add('controls_cp=GET_ACP');

    try
        DBConnection.Connect;
        Result:= DBConnection.Connected;    
    except
        On e:Exception do
        begin
            Result:= false;
            ShowMessage(e.Message);
        end;
    end;
end;
```